# Choose specific values in matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to select some numbers in a MATLAB matrix which have values greater than 4 and set them equal to zero.

For example:

```
A=[5 6 1 3 4 9 2 8 3];
```

Now, replace all values greater than 4 with zeros and store as a new matrix A1:

```
A1=[0 0 1 3 4 0 2 0 3];
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try something like this:

```
A(A>4)=0
```

Here it is:

```
>> A=[5 6 1 3 4 9 2 8 3]

A =

     5     6     1     3     4     9     2     8     3

>> A(A>4)=0

A =

     0     0     1     3     4     0     2     0     3
```

Comment: yes, thanks a lot :), but I want to have it in a new matrix name such as A1=001340203

Comment: @YSF `A1 = A; A1(A1 > 4) = 0;`